# SQL expand query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my database I have this table structure:

```
User table
--------------------
Id      |  User
--------------------
101     |  UserA
102     |  UserB
103     |  UserC

UserGroup table
--------------------
Id      |  Group
--------------------
201     |  GroupA
202     |  GroupB
203     |  GroupC
204     |  GroupD

User2UserGroup table
--------------------
User    |  Group
--------------------
101     |  201
102     |  201
103     |  201
102     |  202
103     |  202
103     |  203
```

and then I have this kind of table, that can contain either user id or userGroupId:

```
My table (Id is either user id or user group id)
--------------------
Id      |  other columns
--------------------
101     |  
102     |  
103     |      
202     |      
203     |      
204     |
```

Is it possible to create a join that will expand this table in something like this:

```
Expanded table
----------------------------------------
UserId  |  GroupId  |  Id
----------------------------------------
101     |  NULL     |  101      
102     |  NULL     |  102        
103     |  NULL     |  103      
101     |  201      |  201      
102     |  201      |  201      
103     |  201      |  201      
102     |  202      |  202      
103     |  202      |  202      
103     |  203      |  203
```

Comment: What if we have same id as both userid and groupid?

Comment: i don't understand what are you trying to achieve, but there is change of similar values for that column. So do you want to list those values in both columns in that case?

Comment: What is the logic behind the desired result?   Why do you want a row with 101 | NULL | 101, when 101 is connected to 201?   Why don't you want a row with 204?   If you can define the logic, getting the result you want is probably pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your userid is never same as groupid, you can try query like below to get desired output.

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/ROSTO66297)**</kbd>

```
select 
UserId   = coalesce(u.id,ug.[user]),
GroupId  = g.id, 
id       = m.id
from 
[MyTable] m left join [User] u
    on m.id=u.id
left join [UserGroup] g
    on m.id=g.id
left join [User2UserGroup] ug
    on g.id=ug.[Group]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if userid and groupid does not have same Values:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GroupID IS NULL THEN ID ELSE UserID END,
  GroupID,
  CASE WHEN groupID IS NULL THEN ID ELSE GROUPID END
FROM Mytable K
FULL JOIN User2UserGroup G
ON K.ID = G.GroupID
ORDER BY GROUPID
```

Comment: I had the choice to vote for deletion or edition, I edited the question as I might have missed the point of the query and because formatting was terrible... But I must admit the query doesn't make any f-ing sense to me.